# Rewrite Javascript function without use of eval() to be more secure

Tags: javascript, security

Can anyone browsing the site help me rewrite this old webapp function to be a bit more secure?

```
    $('table.dataTable.json-data').each(function() {
      console.log("dataTable function thing called");
      var oTable = $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
      var dt_config = oTable.is('[data-dt_config]')? eval('('+oTable.attr('data-dt_config')+')') : {};
      if(oTable.is('[data-dt_settings]')) {
        $.extend(true,dt_config,oTable.data('dt_settings'));
      }
```

So, for context, this Javascript function is called when a user wants to print or export a datatable they have displayed on a page. It generates a new page with the table, and a print menu comes down (or your document is automatically downloaded by your browser).

My client insists that `data-dt_config` can be checked before running in `eval()` to prevent injection, but I genuinely don't even want to use `eval()` at all.

I've been getting much better with perl and php, but Javascript is still out of my element. Please, feel free to explain it to me like I eat crayons, because I'd like to use this post as a good learning opportunity for understanding Javascript more, especially in terms of secure coding.

```
Object
buttons: Array(3)
0: {extend: 'csv'}
1: {extend: 'pdf', orientation: 'landscape'}
2: {extend: 'print', customize: ƒ}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
columns: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
createdRow: ƒ (row,data,dataIndex)
filename: "Material deduction history"
lengthMenu: (2) [Array(4), Array(4)]
source: "material/1007199/history"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

This is the contents of the `dt_config`  variable. It seems to literally just be a set of instruction to make the datatable.

This is the bandaid fix I threw in:
`let tempConfig = oTable.attr('data-dt_config');`

`let testResult = tempConfig.includes("buttons","orientation","customize");`

I still think that would be extremely easy to bypass, so I'm researching something better. Some wisdom on this would be great.

Comment: What's the point of using `eval()` at all? What does that attribute contain?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. Correct me if I'm wrong here, but couldn't I just run the `attr()` call and store it as a variable, then use it if I need it in the `?` operator? I feel like there isn't a point to the `eval()` either.

Comment: If you don't have any idea what values it could have, then *definitely don't `eval` it*.

Comment: Well if the code kind-of works you can always `console.log()` the attribute value, or just look at the values via the browser debugging tool.

Comment: Not sure if anyone is notified, but I updated the post with the contents of the config variable after it runs that `?` operator. It seems to seriously just be a set of instructions to build a data table.

Comment: Have a look at what the `data-dt_config` **attribute** actually contains. If it's just JSON, use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`.

Comment: Hey Felix, so you may be on to something. I ran `console.log("This stupid oTable:",oTable.attr('data-dt_config'));` and it output a mess of config instructions. Added is a small snippet for context `{buttons:[{extend:'csv'},{extend:'pdf',orientation:'landscape'},{extend:'print',customize:function(window){$j(window.document.body).find('table.dataTable').css('visibility','visible');}}]...`

It doesn't seem to be pure json, but rather instructions to run too?

Comment: XSS by design it seems. :) Sorry for not being helpful, but that'll be tough to fix.

Comment: Is there a way to bandaid fix this so I can check the contents of data-dt_config before running it? Something to make the client happy?